# How to start a new activity by clicking on an image using gallery?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gallery, vertical-scrolling

I want to have a something like a screen with a set of scroll-able images where if i click on each image it should start a new activity (). Can I use the android gallery for this purpose? my idea behind using gallery is because i'm using a set of images. so then if i can have them to be in my res folder.

UPDATE

Gallery Class (stack wouldnt let me comment for some reason :( )

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the Android Gallery app or the Gallery Class?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly add an onItemClickListner to the gallery view and use that launch on activity.

```
  gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
      if(position == WantedImage){
          StartActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ActivityToLaunch.class));
      }
  }
```

Comment: also is there a way to make the gallery scroll vertical?

Comment: If you want something that scrolls vertically you should use a listview

Comment: You supply the listview with an adapter that determines how to draw each element. Typically you supply the adapter with a data set, in your case the images you want to display.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: yeah but why cannot we use a vertical gallery?

Comment: Google didn't design the component to do that, you can make your own but that is a lot of work. What feature of the `Gallery` do you need that can't be done with `ListView`

Comment: well I needed something like a scroll view with images and whenever I scroll down, I need to display a text view for that image (like i said before each image will lead to a new activity). I have seen this feature on iPhone and I was thinking of implementing something similar and I want the gallery to be scroll-able vertically.